# Check existing selections in dropdownlist during record edit

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-3

I have some rows in a grid that are editable by a user. When the user clicks the edit button in a grid row, i'm displaying a multi-select dropdownlist 
 ("ddlEditRegionList") with options to choose from. When this dropdownlist is shown i want to keep the already saved selections checked.

I'm trying with the code snippet below but that does get my existing selections.

```
       //Get currently selected options into array regionArr
        var region = $.trim($tr.find(".tdRegion").html());
        $("#hidRegionList").val($.trim($tr.find(".tdRegion").html()));
        var regionArr = region.split(',');
        $tr.find(".tdRegion").html($("#divRegionList"));

        //keep selected options checked in edit mode - this isn't working
        $('#ddlEditRegionList option').map(function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < regionArr.length; i++) {
                if ($.trim($(this).text()) == $.trim(regionArr[i])) {
                    return this;
                }
            }
        }).attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Note that i'm using jquery-3.2.1

Answer (score 0):

```
Try .val() instead of .text(), Like:

if ($.trim($(this).val()) == $.trim(regionArr[i])) {
   return this;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please have a look at [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and then update your answer with some more information. For example, what is the difference that `.val()` makes and why should OP use it instead of `.text()`?